# What columnar cactus species I should select as a rootstock for a Rhipsalis standard?

Tags: indoors, cactus, succulents, variety-selection, grafting

I want to make a standard<sup>(1)</sup> with scions from a [*Rhipsalis pilocarpa*](http://www.rhipsalis.com/species/pilocarpa.htm), or mistletoe cactus. I need a rootstock that:

- Is columnar
- Is unbranched
- Has good longevity (at least 20 years)
- Can adapt to high humidity and light shade
- Has a slim, clean, stem at least 3' long

Stem rigidity is optional, because the plant would be staked at about 3' (by the graft union). I will be side grafting.

I have been considering using a freshly rooted [*Selenicereus*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moonlight_cactus) cutting as the rootstock. Is that a good choice? If so/no, what other options do I have?

<sup>(1) Standard in this context means 'tree form', as a standard rose bush. This term is used with plants that do not naturally grow in tree form, trained to one single stem, or 'trunk', resembling a tree, although smaller in size.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you've seen this link, but it's a great resource for comparing rootstocks.
http://www.kadasgarden.com/Cgraftingstocks.html

From what I can tell, *Cereus jamacaru* seems to fit the bill. It is shade and water tolerant, is columnar, reaches 5 meters in height therefore I believe it must have good longevity.

[It does, unfortunately, branch](http://cactiguide.com/cactus/?genus=Cereus&species=jamacaru).